# How to convert this unstructured data to structured?

Tags: r

The data I have look like this:

```
data <- c("24-March-2017       text1                         874874455221112                Text text text10",
  "25-March-2017       text2                          54654656TEXT                  Text text 11",
  "24-March-2017       text3                          874874455221112               Text text text 12",
  "25-March-2017                  text4                         54654656TEXT                    Text text  13",
  "26-March-2017     text3              54654TEXT   Text text text  14",
  "27-March-2017                text5                       6546TEXT    Text text text 15",
  "28-March-2017      text6                          546476876586TExt   Text text text 16",
  "29-March-2017                  text7      23453453TEXT     Text text  17")
```

[image]

I would like to convert this data to structured format based on spaces between each column. The first three rows looks exactly like how I want the data to look like. The end result needs to look like:

[image]

Basically:

1. the first column (date) starts at zero (no need to change)
2. the second column  must start at position 20
3. the third column starts at position 50
4. the last column starts at 80

Comment: `read.table(text=data,fill=TRUE,header=FALSE)` gets you a nice R dataset that could serve as a clean basis for converting to a new format.

Comment: Why don't you save it as a .csv, then load it using LibreOffice Calc? It has an option of loading text files separated by spaces (among other chars), as well as the option of merging delimiters. Later you can merge the last columns using the function *concatenate*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is based around the data given, and assumes:

- There are four columns
- The first three have no white space within them and are separated by white space
- The last column may contain white space

It pulls out the matching substrings, `rbind`s them into a matrix, removes the global match, converts to a `data.frame` and then passes through `sprintf` to get a fixed width output.

```
data %>%
  regmatches(regexec("^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(.*?)$", .)) %>%
  do.call("rbind", .) %>%
  .[, -1] %>%
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  c(list("%-20s%-30s%-30s%s"), .) %>%
  do.call("sprintf", .)

# [1] "24-March-2017       text1                         874874455221112               Text text text10"  
# [2] "25-March-2017       text2                         54654656TEXT                  Text text 11"      
# [3] "24-March-2017       text3                         874874455221112               Text text text 12" 
# [4] "25-March-2017       text4                         54654656TEXT                  Text text  13"     
# [5] "26-March-2017       text3                         54654TEXT                     Text text text  14"
# [6] "27-March-2017       text5                         6546TEXT                      Text text text 15" 
# [7] "28-March-2017       text6                         546476876586TExt              Text text text 16" 
# [8] "29-March-2017       text7                         23453453TEXT                  Text text  17"
```

Comment: great answer. I would like to apply to other tables. How the regexec would look like if I have 6 columns and: (1) no white spaces in 1st column  (2) we have 1-5 white spaces in the second column (all single spaces)   (3) third and fourth columns have 1 to 3 single spaces (4) no white spaces in the 5th column and finally (5) the 6th column same as above contains multiple spaces.

Comment: What about spacing between columns?

Comment: 1st column starts at zero, 2nd column at 20, third column at 50, 4th column at 80, 5th column at 120, and last column at 180.

Comment: If the input widths are fixed you should be able to use `read.fwf`. If not, are there always at least two spaces between columns?

Comment: input widths isn't fixed and yes there always at least two spaces between columns.

Comment: You could do `^(\\S+)\\s\\s+(.*?)\\s\\s+(.*?)\\s\\s+(.*?)\\s\\s+(\\S+)\\s\\s+(.*?)$`

Answer (score 3):

```
do.call('rbind', lapply( df, function( x ) {  # loop through vector df
  x <- strsplit( x, "\ ")[[1]]                # split string by spaces
  x <- x[which( unlist( lapply(x, nchar) ) > 0 )]  # remove zero length strings
  x <- c(x[1:3], paste( x[4:length(x)], collapse = " ") )  # collapse all elements from 4 to end
  return( x)  # return formatted vector
}))

#                 [,1]    [,2]             [,3]                 [,4]               
# [1,] "24-March-2017" "text1" "874874455221112"  "Text text text10" 
# [2,] "25-March-2017" "text2" "54654656TEXT"     "Text text 11"     
# [3,] "24-March-2017" "text3" "874874455221112"  "Text text text 12"
# [4,] "25-March-2017" "text4" "54654656TEXT"     "Text text 13"     
# [5,] "26-March-2017" "text3" "54654TEXT"        "Text text text 14"
# [6,] "27-March-2017" "text5" "6546TEXT"         "Text text text 15"
# [7,] "28-March-2017" "text6" "546476876586TExt" "Text text text 16"
# [8,] "29-March-2017" "text7" "23453453TEXT"     "Text text 17"
```

**Based on @thelatemail comment**

```
df <- read.table(text=df,fill=TRUE,header=FALSE)
df[, 4] <- apply( df[, 4:ncol(df)], 1, function( x ) {
  paste( x[ ! is.na( x ) ], collapse = ' ') } )
df <- df[, 1:4]
df
#              V1    V2               V3                V4
# 1 24-March-2017 text1  874874455221112  Text text text10
# 2 25-March-2017 text2     54654656TEXT      Text text 11
# 3 24-March-2017 text3  874874455221112 Text text text 12
# 4 25-March-2017 text4     54654656TEXT      Text text 13
# 5 26-March-2017 text3        54654TEXT Text text text 14
# 6 27-March-2017 text5         6546TEXT Text text text 15
# 7 28-March-2017 text6 546476876586TExt Text text text 16
# 8 29-March-2017 text7     23453453TEXT      Text text 17
```

**Data:**

```
df <- c("24-March-2017       text1                         874874455221112                Text text text10",
          "25-March-2017       text2                          54654656TEXT                  Text text 11",
          "24-March-2017       text3                          874874455221112               Text text text 12",
          "25-March-2017                  text4                         54654656TEXT                    Text text  13",
          "26-March-2017     text3              54654TEXT   Text text text  14",
          "27-March-2017                text5                       6546TEXT    Text text text 15",
          "28-March-2017      text6                          546476876586TExt   Text text text 16",
          "29-March-2017                  text7      23453453TEXT     Text text  17")
```